# Connecting to CloudSQL from App Engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Go app running on App Engine, and a first generation CloudSQL instance running. I can connect to the SQL server from dev using a TCP connection, specifying the SQL server's IP. But I cannot connect from the deployed instance, using the CloudSQL driver.

Sample code

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"
    _ "google.golang.org/appengine/cloudsql"
)

if (dev) {
    sql.Open("mymysql", "tcp:1.2.3.4:3306*database/user/pass")
} else {
    sql.Open("mymysql", "cloudsql:project-id:instance-name*database/user/pass")
}
```

(Yes, I'm substituting `database`, `user`, `pass`, `project-id`, and `instance-name` for their correct values in my real code)

When running locally (via `goapp serve`) I can connect and query the database - everything works great.
However, when connecting from the deployed instance, I get the following error:

> Received #1045 error from MySQL server: "Access denied for user 'readonly'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I have made sure that my App Engine instance is authorized (SQL > Instance > Access Control > Authorization), and I'm using the same user in both cases.

I've found something resembling my error message on the [Diagnosing Issues with Cloud SQL Instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/diagnose-issues) page, but the suggested solution is to connect with SSL if SSL is enabled (I have not enabled SSL for the server).

> If you get an error message like:
>
> ```
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'1.2.3.4' (using password: YES)
> ```
>
> when you connect, verify that you are using the correct
> password and that you are connecting over SSL if the instance requires
> it.

Seeing as how this has given me so much trouble, I also tried connecting via IP address from the App Engine instance, but the socket connection is denied.

Comment: Do you have a readonly@localhost user setup in MySQL?

Comment: Any updates on the question of Vadim? It's a pretty basic sanity-check, but might just work.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did verify that the read-only user was setup (and was even readonly@%). In the end, I set up a second generation instance and was able to connect to it without any issues.

Comment: You could self-answer that, I suppose. Glad to hear!